# Sails v0.10.x not sending update or addedTo messages when in Production Mode

Tags: sails.js, sails.io.js

I'm running into an issue with Sails WebSockets in production mode. When I run Sails in development mode - i.e. `sails lift` - I receive all messages on the firehose. However, when I run Sails in production mode - i.e. `sails lift --prod` - I only receive create messages.

For example, my socket listener code looks like:

```
io.socket.get('/firehose', function nowListeningToFirehose(message) {

    // Attach a listener which fires every time the server publishes
    // a message to the firehose, then dispatch messages to simple handlers
    io.socket.on('firehose', function newMessageFromSails(message) {
        console.log('Firehose message: ', message);

        switch (message.model) {

            // Handle messages related to Rooms
            case 'room':
                processRoomMessage(message);
                break;

            // Handle messages related to Person(s)
            case 'person':
                processPersonMessage(message);
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    });
```

When I run in development mode, I get `update` and `addedTo` messages for room. I also get `create` and `update` messages for person. However, when I run in production mode. I only get `create` messages for user, no `update` or `addedTo` messages.

I am running Sails v.0.10.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Per the following log message from Sails, the firehose is turned off in production mode.

```
Warning: A client socket was just subscribed to the firehose, but the environment is set to `production`. Firehose messages are only delivered in the development environment.
```

It doesn't explain why I'm getting `create` messages, but does at least explain why I don't get `update` or `addedTo` messages.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a bug in the Sails pubsub implementation that causes firehose messages to be send out on `publishCreate` calls.  It's being patched now.  As you saw in the warning (and as is [stated in the documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.sockets/sails.sockets.subscribeToFirehose.html) the firehose is strictly intended as a development tool.  Thanks for the report!